# Scala error: ';' expected but '=' found

Tags: scala, matrix, rotation, syntax-error

Can someone help me understand why the following code causes the above error?

The code is for rotation of a 2D array by 90 degrees.

```
def rotate90(block: Array[Array[Int]]) = {
  var size: Int = block.size
  var i: Int = 0
  var j: Int = size - 1
  while (j >= 0) {
    while (i <= j) {
      val a = block[j][i]
      val b = block[j - i][j]
      block[j][i] = b
      block[j - i][j] = a 
      i = i + 1
    }
    j = j - 1
  }
  return block
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please tell us where exactly the error occurs? Without this information it will be very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Array access notation (and in general collection) is `()` in scala, so `block[j][i]` should be `block(j)(i)` and so on.

Comment: Akso `val a: Array[Array[Int]] = block[j][i]`? `a` is an Int (at least, `block(j)(i)` is an Int). Your code seems rather confused. You can remove the explicit type for `a` and `b` in any case, the compiler will work it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rotate90(block: Array[Array[Int]]) = {
   val copy: Array[Array[Int]] = Array.ofDim[Int](block.length, block(0).length)

   for (w <- 0 until block(0).length;
        h <- 0 until block.length) {
            copy(h).update(w, block(block(0).length - 1 - w)(h))
   }
   copy
}
```

Above is scala solution for you problem. Maybe you better understand how arrays in scala works.